# Cannot import name

Tags: flask, импорт, sqlalchemy, python-import

Ошибка импорта:

> ImportError: cannot import name 'User'

Можете подсказать, как исправить?

**main.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///tmp.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from app.models import *

db.create_all()

from app.algo import funct
```

**algo.py**

```
from app.main import db
from app.models import User

def funct(): #declaration
```

**models.py**

```
from app.main import db

class User(db.Model): #declaration
```

Comment: У вас `app` это пакет?

Comment: @gil9red, это просто папка в корневой директории

Comment: там есть `__init__.py` файл?

Comment: @gil9red, нет. При создании проекта в PyCharm была просто создана папка app. А уже в ней пишется весь исходный код

Comment: @gil9red, если переместить все файлы из app в project, то можно будет писать без app.*

Comment: в этом и дело `from app.models User` подразумевает что из модуля models.py, который в пакете app нужно импортировать объект User

Comment: @gil9red, наверное, мы все же друг друга не поняли. Давайте еще раз. Есть Project, в нем содержится папка venv, logs, app. В папке app содержится main.py, models.py, algo.py. Ни в одной из этих папок __init__.py нет. Мне, кажется, что проблема в циклическом импорте, но не очень понимаю, как его исправить

Comment: Понял, тогда просто: `from models import User`, раз `main.py` находится в той же папке что и `models.py`. Жаль, что в вопросе у вас структура папок не была описана )

Comment: @gil9red, это приводит к ошибке

Comment: Печально, вот у меня не привело это к ошибке, когда повторял вашу структуру модулей

Comment: > "В папке app содержится main.py, models.py, algo.py"

Если так, то следует импорт написать так:
`from .models import User`  - убрать `app`, оставить первую точку (текущий, относительный каталог)

Answer (score 1):

> "В папке app содержится main.py, models.py, algo.py"

Если так, то следует импорт написать так:
`from .models import User`  - убрать `app`, оставить первую точку (текущий, относительный каталог)